# Making my Discord.py bot send an animated emoji

Tags: animation, discord, emoji, discord.py

I have attempted this as my code.

```py
@client.command()
async def party(ctx):
    party = client.get_emoji(786138532069900350)
    await ctx.send('{}'.format(party))
```

but it replies as `None`
It's an animated default discord emoji [Emoji](https://cdn.discordapp.com/emojis/786138532069900350.gif?v=1)
So what am I doing wrong?

Comment: please insert code instead of image, please give reproducible code

Comment: https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html?highlight=get_emoji#discord.Client.get_emoji `The custom emoji or None if not found.`

How did you get the emoji id? Is your bot in the same discord guild the emoji is available in? Are you using the emoji cross guilds or in the same guild?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have noticed that your `get_emoji` variable name is `party`, the same as command (or function's) name, That's why it is returning `None`. Please change the variable name to something other then function's name.
Example:

```py
@client.command()
async def party(ctx):
    partyemoji = client.get_emoji(786138532069900350) # problem was here
    await ctx.send(partyemoji) # instead of formatting string simply use variable name.
```

P.S: If it still returns `None` check if your emoji ID is valid or not.

Comment: yep. im a "bit" late but yes that was what the problem was :')

Answer (score 2):

To send an animated emoji you should find the emoji name and the emoji id..

To send a normal emoji we use this format:
`<:emojiname:emojiid>`

To send an animated one we use:
`<a:emojiname:emojiid>`

After that you need to edit your code as follows..

```
@client.command()
async def party(ctx):
    party = "<a:youremojiname:emojiid>" #assigning the emoji
    await ctx.send(party) #sending the emoji
```

Comment: yep that should work but notice the function name and variable name is the same! as user11936470 pointed out, that seems to be the problem! p.s i am late.

Answer (score 1):

With a some research I found https://github.com/Rapptz/discord.py/issues/390:

Basically what it includes to use custom emojis

To use a custom emoji, you use the emoji name, then it's id which can be
extracted from the middle id from its link id.

For example, the id of this emoji is:

Original link: https://cdn.discordapp.com/emojis/3489241209391.png?v=1
Emoji id: 3489241209391

In the example shown below, it would appear as the emoji when sent in a message

```
<:emoji_name:emoji_id>

example: <:myemoji:3489241209391>
```

With an animated emoji is the same, but append an "a" at the front

`<a:emoji_name:emoji_id>`

Answer (score 1):

Or if none of these methods work, simply send it like:

```
await ctx.send("https://cdn.discordapp.com/emojis/836234327016210482.gif?v=1")
```

Comment: You could explain in detail how/why this solution works to solve OP's question/problem.  I am a reviewer.  StackOverflow requested review because you are a new contributor.  Your answer is appreciated & helpful.  This comment is intended to help you make a good answer into an excellent one.

Comment: im a "bit" late but i wanted to send that as an emoji not a gif ;')
thanks for the answer tho!